# Approach for cross platform chat application with back-end in c#

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, wcf, chat

I want to create a cross platform chat app with backend in c#
I searched for an approach to do so and found that I can do so with http requests to handlers on my server and use the response accordingly.
So till now I made the handlers which can add users, login, send and receive messages using database for storage.

Now I am making android client for that and to get messages for user I need to do http requests at a specific interval (3 seconds).

I feel it is not a good approach to do this. I am making this app for a target audience of nearly 30000. They would be able to chat one on one at a single session.

I just want to know if I am going in right direction or There is far more better ways to make chat apps using backend.

I have heard about wcf but I am not clear with what approach should I take. Please guide me about approaches for chat application.

**Edit**
An example of little working of any famous chat app like whats app, facebook messenger would be a great help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with HTTP, but I'd suggest using TCP instead. There's a very solid base for a C# based TCP server on *codereview* [right here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5306/c-tcp-socket-server) which will outline how to deal with `Socket` objects how to handle connections properly.

The main perk of going about it this way is that you can connect your client to the server, and the client can be virtually any language, it doesn't have to be C# - as long as the language supports sockets, you'll be fine.

On top of that you can have the client listen to the server, which removes the need of polling the server for new messages every couple of seconds; the client socket will receive data when the server sends it, and you can handle it right away, nearly in real-time, whereas if you'd poll the server for new messages over HTTP every - say 3 seconds - you'll always end up with a delay in your chat service, which is something I think you will want to avoid.

See the code sample on CodeReview I linked above, and read up on how `Socket`s work in C#, how TCP works in terms of guarantees (TCP guarantees that whatever is sent over it will end up on the other side in the same order, but not necessarily in one packet, etc) and I'm pretty confident you'll be able to make a excellent chat app if you put it all to good use.

Edit: I just noticed the WCF tag on your post. I'd personally steer clear of it for this specific project since you want to achieve cross-platform support; try going as low-level as you possibly can for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and you are correct I would like to do it without any delay and with minimum load. I am considering sockets as the best choice now but just out of curiosity can you tell me how whats app, kik and apps like it work? Do they use sockets too??

Comment: I haven't looked into those specifically, but I'd assume they do. I highly doubt they poll a server every x seconds, especially on mobile platforms where your CPU time is limited while running in the background. I'm only guessing here but I'm thinking they use that CPU time to display notifications whenever they have received a new message from the server.

Comment: I just saw the working of sockets in web browser and its way cool.